# What is neuromuscular endurance in the world of bicycling?

Tags: cadence

I read the term neuromuscular endurance perhaps something related to having your brain not accustomed to high speed pedalling. I'm curious as it is related to bicycling cadence and I'm working on that.

Comment: "Neuromuscular" simply denotes that part of human physiology that has to with how the motor neurons interact with the voluntary muscles.  To the extent that cadence is controlled by the nerves, it has to do with cadence, but it has to do with many other things as well.  Much of "muscle fatigue", et al, has as much to do with the nerves as with the muscles.

Comment: If you're interested in this question because of its relationship to cadence, perhaps you will want to read this: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/12518/what-is-the-optimal-cadence

Comment: Do you have a reference to where you came across this term? Endurance is typically discussed in terms of whether it's aerobic or anaerobic.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you've misunderstood the concept a little. There is no neuromuscular endurance power range quite like the aerobic or anaerobic power zones. There are however neuromuscular adaptations which will affect your endurance and cycling performance.

The nerve connections to muscles are how your brain controls them. Through training, you're able to create more nerve connections to a muscle, which will also have faster firing. This allows better activation of your body's muscle fibres. The end result of this is better pedalling efficiency and better peak power.

The best way to train for these adaptations is through strength training. When training high weight low reps, your muscle is forced to recruit far more muscle fibres than it ever needs to when cycling. Even a maximal sprint effort doesn't come close to the torque requires for heavy deadlifts or leg press. To meet these requirements, your body makes these neuromuscular adaptations which in turn are beneficial to cycling performance, which is where the endurance relationship comes into the equation.

[This article](http://www.achieveptc.com/improve-your-cycling-performance-with-neuromuscular-drills/) discusses the concept.

Comment: You can _strengthen_ the neural connections through training, but I am pretty certain your statement about increasing the _number_ of connections is false. What can increase is the number of muscle fibers that are recruited during a given task. This an come from improved coordination and strengthen neural connections.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, how a muscle performs depends on it's size, available fuel, how frequently it gets signalled by the nervous system and how well it responds to those signals - hence we talk about the *neuromuscular system*. Training improves muscle mass, nerve signalling and muscle response.

'Neuromuscular endurance' just refers to the endurance performance of that whole system.

Another article:https://www.livestrong.com/article/415559-neuromuscular-adaptations-due-to-strength-training/